# SQL запрос ищущий по условиям для двух столбцов

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Таблица факультетов]
Запрос должен находить в таблице факультетов технические факультеты с числом студентов превышающим 200

```
Select * 
from dbo.Факультеты
where 
Название_факультета not like '%Медицинский%' and
Название_факультета not like '%Гуманитарный%' and
Название_факультета not like '%управления%' and
Название_факультета not like '%Фило%' and
Максимальное_количество_студентов > 200
```

Как правильно написать такой запрос, так как мой ничего не выводит, хотя есть что

Comment: С виду все отлично и должно работать. уберите условия. и начинайте добавлять по одному, начиная с Максимальное_количество_студентов > 200 и смотрите как сокращается выборка

Comment: Префикс `N` забыли?

Comment: @Mike, не находит ничего даже только с условием про число студентов

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , Что за префикс? Я только учусь.

Comment: А без условий все находит и показывает ? Ну такого не может быть. Только если это не та таблица или БД ... Или то, чем вы выполняете запрос выводит их как то не так как вы ожидаете.

Comment: @Mike, а вот сейчас нашло как надо